# Use Single Blog Post as Site Front Page Without Redirect

Tags: permalinks, homepage

I am attempting to do something similar to the accepted answer on this question [Is it possible to use a single custom post as the site front page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42461/is-it-possible-to-use-a-single-custom-post-as-the-site-front-page)

My problem is that this implementation causes a redirect.

So for example if I add the code below to twentyeleven functions.php on a default WordPress install, and then select the `Hello World` post from the `reading->front page` drop down my home url such as `mysite.com` will redirect to `mysite.com/?p=1`. So it is impossible to actually stay on the home page because of this redirect.

Is it possible to avoid this redirect? If so, the solution below will be great for showing a post or custom post as the home page.

```
add_filter( 'get_pages', 'add_pages_to_dropdown', 10, 2 );

function add_pages_to_dropdown( $pages, $r ){
    if ( ! isset( $r[ 'name' ] ) )
        return $pages;

    if ( 'page_on_front' == $r[ 'name' ] ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post'
        );

        $portfolios = get_posts( $args );
        $pages = array_merge( $pages, $portfolios );
    }

    return $pages;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a single custom post as the site front page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42461/is-it-possible-to-use-a-single-custom-post-as-the-site-front-page)

Comment: Based on comments below, this is not a *new* question, but rather a *continuation* of the linked question. Rather than starting a new question, the original question should be updated with this clarifying condition regarding the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just copy/paste my answer to that question, here:

There are many ways to accomplish this, though some are more advanced than others:

1. Mark the blog post as **sticky**, and then set Posts per Page to **1** (`Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`)
2. Create a custom `front-page.php` template, and query the post in question, either via the **sticky** post designation, or via custom post meta
3. Create a custom `front-page.php` template, and create a dynamic sidebar (i.e. Widget area), in which you add a Widget to display the post in question
4. (Insert lots of other methods here...)

But I have to ask: **why not just put that blog post content in a *static Page*, and then assign that static Page as the Front Page?**

#### Edit

Also: be sure that you have **pretty permalinks** enabled, via `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`.

Comment: Chip, your first solution simply shows the post on the home page as if it was an archive. It does not show the actual post. Your second and third options are not relevant to the question... Also, it is not possible to make a custom post type sticky without the use of a plugin.

Comment: What's this about "***custom post type***"? Your question referenced using **single blog posts**, not custom post types.

Comment: Yeah, if I can get a post to work, I should not have a problem getting a CPT to work. The real issue here is avoiding the redirect

Comment: But CPTs are covered in the other question. Refer to *that* question for CPTs.

Comment: Also, the second and third examples are *absolutely relevant* to the question. Both are effective means to display a single blog post as the site front page.

Comment: Not with the code I have shown... I have the problem solved. I am simply trying to avoid the redirect. So copying and pasting your answer was about as helpful as this conversation.

Comment: So, you're confirming that this is a *continuation* of your previous question, in which case, my original comment stands: **you should modify your original question, rather than starting a *new* question**.

Comment: that is not my original question... This is a completely new question. I AM TRYING TO AVOID THE REDIRECT THAT HAPPENS. Does that part make sense? I noticed you edited my question to remove that part, so I put it back in...

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far has been to take the `reading->front page` option out of the equation and go with a custom post type settings page.

Adding a settings page requires a bit of code but it can be done starting with the `add_submenu_page();` function.

Then you can use the `pre_get_posts` action to alter the query by using that option you set like so

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );

function my_pre_get_posts($query){
        $option = get_option('my_option');
        if(is_front_page()){
                $query->set('p', $option);
                $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }

    }
```

This allows you to avoid having to create a front-page.php file which could be a duplication of a more specific theme file. The drawbacks to this are obvious, you now have an extra settings page. Not sure there is really a "correct" answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a copy single.php and name it home.php and put it in your theme folder.
Wordpress will use that as a home now.
Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Then you just change the loop inside your home.php (based on single.php) to look like it's explained here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post

So this:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

Becomes this:

```
<?php
query_posts( 'p=5' );
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

Where the line "query_posts" specify the postID that you want as a home (check that on wp-admin side). In the example, p=5 will query for postID = 5.

Or you can just redefine a new loop using http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query method to ensure nothing else be broken with the new loop.

Pretty neat and simple.