# How to Make my Homepage Display a Single Specific Post?

Tags: posts, homepage

This is kinda tricky, I tried looking for a solution but failed.

I want to make mu homepage (www.mywebsite.com) display a post (www.mywebsite.com/my-first-post). I basically want to make a post as my front page!
I do not want to get post content into the homepage.

I tried to do a redirection, it worked well, but the problem is when I share my website address over Facebook and tried to click the URL (www.mywebsite.com), I get to the homepage and no redirection happen.

Extra info.

I use Facebook Open Graph tag.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to go to Settings > Reading and choose "Your homepage displays" - "a static page." That will give you a dropdown so you can choose the specific WP Page you want to display.

Other options include creating a child theme or a custom theme, or in `functions.php` using `pre_get_posts()` to modify the main query on the homepage to only pull the 1 specific Post or Page you want to display there (this may not work in all themes - it just depends on what theme you're using).

Comment: Thanks, but the first part of your answer does not address my question. I do not want to have another page as my front page, rather I want to have a custom post as my front page. I was checking this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42461/is-it-possible-to-use-a-single-custom-post-as-the-site-front-page If you can explain to me the answer mentioned -I'm not good at coding- would be great!